# How to close semantic ui modal in another react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In my main component I can open a modal by clicking on an icon. The content of the modal is a separate component, which is calling a method.
If the method call is successful, I want to close the modal. But how can I do this?

**Main component**

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal trigger={ <Icon name='tags' /> } >
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <div>
                            <Header floated='left'>Title</Header>
                            <Button floated='right'>A Button</Button>
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Content>

                        <ModalContent />

                    </Modal.Content>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Modal content**

```
class ModalContent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {}
    }

    handleClick() {
        method.call(
            { param },
            (error, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    // Now close the modal
                }
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={this.handleClick} content='Save' />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add an `onClose` property to `<Modal>` element. See example below:

```
<Modal
    trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Show Modal</Button>}
    open={this.state.modalOpen}
    onClose={this.handleClose}
  >
```

Then you can add `onClose` function to a button in your modal. Full example from the docs:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal#modal-example-controlled

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `onSuccess` method as a props :

in the parent :

```
 <ModalContent onSuccess={this.onModalSuccess}/>
```

in the child component :

```
handleClick() {
   method.call(
        { param },
        (error, result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.props.onSuccess()
            }
        }
    );
}
```

In this way you keep your open/close logic in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

semantic-ui have property `open`. Just set `true` or `false`

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      open: false
  }
  open = () => this.setState({ open: true })
  close = () => this.setState({ open: false })
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal open={this.state.open} trigger={ <Icon name='tags' /> } >
                <Modal.Header>
                    <div>
                        <Header floated='left'>Title</Header>
                        <Button floated='right'>A Button</Button>
                    </div>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Content>

                    <ModalContent />

                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```